# An example of an infinitely differentiable function with compact support

Tags: calculus

Could anyone give me a function infinitely differentiable on the real line and having a compact support? And the function must be nonnegative and normalized, i.e. the integration of the function on the real line must be one.

I tried to think of one myself, but it seems trickier than expected.

Comment: You need to construct such a function out of a function such as $$f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x}, & x>0 \\ 0, & x\le 0\end{cases}.$$

Comment: I tried, but couldn't satisfy the compact support condition.

Comment: Ah, build another one, $g$, that dies smoothly at $x=1$, say, and then what can you do with the two of them?

Comment: What about the function $f(x)=0$ for all $x$?

Comment: Oh, sorry I forgot to put another condition that the function must be normalized. I made an edit.

Comment: @TedShifrin and Merideth  , This type of question always makes me think of ODEs spontaneously generating interesting solutions out of zero initial conditions, and the world springing into existence out of nothing.

Comment: @Merideth: Everyone is doing the problem for you, but if you want to try to solve by thinking through what I said, do so, and *then* worry about normalizing the integral once you're done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The classic bump function is nice:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} & \textrm{if }|x|<1 \\
0 & \textrm{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

I doubt it's normalized, but you just need to divide it by $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)\;dt$ to normalize.

Comment: Is f continuous ? As you have given differentiable so it should be but I not able to understand , can you please explain?

Answer (score 7):

Let $a, r\ (r>0)$ be numbers. The function: 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\mathrm e^{\tfrac1{(x-a)^2-r^2}}&\text{if}\enspace \lvert x-a\rvert <r\\
0&\text{if}\enspace \lvert x-a\rvert\ge r\end{cases},$$
is an example of a $\mathcal C^\infty$ function with support in $[a-r,a+r]$.

Answer (score 6):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ as small as you want and take $\frac{f}{\|f\|_{L^1}}$ with
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&-\varepsilon\leq x\leq \varepsilon\\
\exp\left(-\frac{(|x|-\varepsilon)^2}{4\varepsilon^2-x^2}\right)&\varepsilon\leq |x|\leq 2\varepsilon\\
0&|x|\geq 2\varepsilon
\end{cases}.$$

Here an example for $\varepsilon=1/2$ ($f$ is not normalized):
[image]