# Proof that a function with compact support is inifinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to find a function that is constant on some interval and with compact support that is also in $\mathcal{C}^\infty$.

I know there are plenty of examples in this site, for example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1283801) the following example is given

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&-\varepsilon\leq x\leq \varepsilon\\
\exp\left(-\frac{(|x|-\varepsilon)^2}{4\varepsilon^2-x^2}\right)&\varepsilon\leq |x|\leq 2\varepsilon\\
0&|x|\geq 2\varepsilon
\end{cases}.$$

But, when plotting its second derivative I get the following

[image]

which is far from being continuous, so is this example incorrect?

In the case it is incorrect, how can I construct a function that has that form, zero outside some interval, constant in some subinterval inside the previous one and infinitely differentiable?

And more important, how can we prove that it is in fact infinitely differentiable? Because I don't see how it would be any obvious for this kind of piecewise functions.

Comment: There are many posts on this topic. On the right hand pane of this page you see several links. The very first one will give you some basic ideas.

Comment: The reason your graph looks disconnected is computation error, not an actual problem with the function. You can prove that all derivatives of $$\begin{cases}e^{-1/x}&x > 0\\0&x \le 0\end{cases}$$ at $x = 0$ are $0$ themselves. It is the classic example of a function which is not equal to its Taylor series. At $|x| = 2\varepsilon$, your function is a translate or translate with reflection of that one, multiplied by another function which is smooth in the neighborhood. The graphing calculator is not accurately handling the function near these values.